# How to reduce memory footprint for windows application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Integrating few controls of WPF into windows forms application has increased the memory usage from 20 MB to 50 MB. How could reduce the memory usage?

Comment: You meant MB's, not KBs right?

Comment: How many of which controls? Which amount of data do they hold?

Comment: @CodyManix: Iam using UserControl of WPF containing listview with some images and several panels, buttons,toolstrips, forms, labels of win-forms controls

Comment: You are using WPF controls in a Windows Forms application?  Is there a  reason you are not using a WPF application?

Comment: The older application is in Win-forms, later we got a new requirement for that we need a WPF listview which can add any control like button, progressbar into the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Memory Profiler such as [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [RedGate ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html#Memory_profiling) to see where your memory is going.

If it's 20->50KB, that sounds completely reasonable.  If it's 20->50MB then that sounds like something else happened, and maybe the other forms are simply a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Try using UI virtualization on your list views to not render the items that haven't been shown yet.

http://www.kirupa.com/net/ui_virtualization_pg1.htm